# Reset start end sequence to start from 1 in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, sequence

I have a dataframe with columns giving the start and end of each row. I want the sequence to start with 1 in the first row.

My dataframe looks as follows:

```
 > df1
  start end
1     5   7
2     8  12
3    13  15
4    16  20
```

And I want to transform it into something like this:

```
> df2
  start end
1     1   3
2     4   8
3     9  11
4    12  16
```

Comment: Maybe try `df1 - 4`

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Subtract the first element of `start` and add 1 to all elements.

```
df2 <- df1 - df1$start[1] + 1

df2
##   start end
## 1     1   3
## 2     4   8
## 3     9  11
## 4    12  16
```

**2)** This also worls:

```
library (dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(across() - first(start) + 1)
```

### Note

`df1` in reproducible form

```
Lines <- "  start end
1     5   7
2     8  12
3    13  15
4    16  20"
df1 <- read.table(text = Lines)
```